# Google - DFP SB login error

Tags: authorization, adsense, google-dfp, google-account

I'm trying to sign up for [DFP small business](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/publishers/small-business/) service with an enabled AdSense account.

After submitting with the [apply form](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/dfpsbsignupen/), I am still unable to log into DFP account and keep seeing this error:

> **Unauthorized Access**
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience, but you are not authorized to
>   visit this page. If you believe this is an error, please contact your
>   account manager.

I received nothing in my email (activation link or any message about it) and I cannot log in to check any information or settings about my account.

I also followed [this answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dfp/J1UVFllOQZw) to solve the issue but nothing really worked.

Is there anything I can do other than contact google and wait a long time to get useful response?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use DFP, you need to sign an agreement with Google. DFP is not for free. You should contact Google.